# Vuejs Rebind an Html Select List

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a data-grid.
When the user clicks the "edit" button for a row in the grid, the div which contains the grid is made invisible (using `v-if`) and another div which contains an update form for that item is made visible (also using `v-if`).

As an added complication, the "edit" form contains a selectlist. This is bound to an array, but the array to which it is bound varies, depending on which item is selected in the grid (the items in the grid are different kinds of things).

How do I get that selectlist to rebind each time an item in the grid is clicked on for edit.

I realise I could do this by making a component, but that to me is overkill.

Is perhaps a slot the answer? Not sure how to proceed.

This is the relevant code:

```
<b-row v-if="editClaimFormVisible" class="mt-6 justify-content-md-center">
  <b-col cols="6">
    <b-form @submit.prevent="editClaimSubmit">
      <b-form-group label="Enter New Claim Value:">
        <b-form-select v-model="selectedClaimForEdit.claimValue" :options="getClaimOptions()" value-field="id" text-field="name" required>
          <template #first>
            <b-form-select-option :value="null" disabled>-- Please select a claim --</b-form-select-option>
          </template>
        </b-form-select>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group>
        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Save</b-button>
      </b-form-group>
    </b-form>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Comment: Vue templates are declarative - simply declare how the SELECT's options will be populated, e.g. from an Array-type property of the currently edited item.

Comment: @IVOGELOV That works for the 1st item selected. But the Computed property only runs once and every item gets the same select list. I want the Computed property to run every time an item is selected. It looks like I'll have to use a Component and put that very small piece of html in a whole big component. Overkill. Adds clutter. Not great.

Comment: Don't use a computed property for something that can be easily put directly inside the template and thus have direct access to the current item inside your `v-for` - use the elegance and simplicity of Vue templates.

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes. Fair enough. Computed properties was not the answer. Toggling a field in the class with a declarative binding to that field was the answer. Like all the other bindings.